# Calcular diferencia entre dos fechas en Android

Tags: android

soy nuevo programando Android y estoy tratando de calcular la diferencia entre dos fechas para mostrarlo en un TextView pero no lo logro

Answer (score 2):

Digamos que tienes tus fechas en dos TextView o en dos variables lo que se podría hacer es convertir esa cadena en entero y hacer una comparación.

> Aquí un pequeño ejemplo

```
String fecha1 = "22/08/2017";
String fecha2 = "20/08/2016";
//Con la función replace reemplazamos las barras / por null o nada (en pocas palabras las quitamos)
String nuevaFecha1 = fecha1.replace("/", ""); //el valor seria 22082017
String nuevaFecha2 = fecha2.replace("/", ""); //el valor seria 20082016
//Variables que almacenan los valores de las fechas anteriores pero convertidas a enteros con la función Integer.valueOf(valor_cadena)
int valorFecha1 = Integer.valueOf(nuevaFecha1); // convertimos el String 22082017 a int 22082017
int valorFecha2 = Integer.valueOf(nuevaFecha2); // convertimos el String 20082016a int 20082016
//Esta variable almacenara la fecha mayor comparada de los dos valores
String fechaMayor;
//Comparamos cual de las dos fechas es mayor
if(valorFecha1 > valorFecha2){
     fechaMayor = String.valueOf(valorFecha1);
}else{
     fechaMayor = String.valueOf(valorFecha2);
}
//Imprimimos el valor en Log de la fecha mayor, solo cambia para que este valor cargue en tu TextView o EditText

 Log.v("TAG_FECHA_MAYOR", fechaMayor);
```

> Quizás te sirva este código.

Esta es una función para obtener la fecha que el usuario elija:

```
public void obtenerFecha(){

        //Calendario para obtener fecha & hora
        public final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    
        final int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        final int anio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        DatePickerDialog recogerFecha = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                int mesActual = month + 1;
                String diaFormateado = (dayOfMonth < 10)? "0" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth):String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                String mesFormateado = (mesActual < 10)? "0" + String.valueOf(mesActual):String.valueOf(mesActual);

                mEtFecha.setText(diaFormateado + "/" + mesFormateado +"/"+ year);

            }
        },anio, mes, dia);

        recogerFecha.show();

    }
```

Con esto puedes almacenarlo en mEtFecha, que vendría a ser un EditText o TextView.

Comment: no entiendo, la idea es restar la fecha1 con la fecha2 y obtener los años, mes, dias de dicha diferencia

Comment: Las primeras 2 variables contienen la fecha en un formato "31/07/2017", las dos siguientes quitan el carácter */*, para que quede así  31072017 y se asemeja a un número y los dos últimos almacenan el valor de las fechas convertidas de String a enteros y por ultimo la comparación de las fechas convertidas a enteros.

Comment: lo se, pero solo me dice que fecha es mas actual, pero no me calcula la diferencia, no me dice que por ejemplo 1 año

Comment: Seria mas fácil si comparte su código

Comment: Bueno recién te entiendo tu quieres el rango entre fechas, que es muy diferente a la diferencia entre dos fechas

Comment: exacto, yo quiero calcular por ejemplo
fecha1= "22/08/2017"
fecha2="12/08/2017"

el resultado... faltan 10 dias para la fecha1

popr ahora mi codigo es este:
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
String dia = String.valueOf(today.monthDay);
String mes = String.valueOf(today.month+1);
String año = String.valueOf(today.year);
String hora = String.valueOf(today.hour);
String min = String.valueOf(today.minute);
String seg = String.valueOf(today.second);

Comment: Haber quizá el código que esta en esta página te sirva  [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)